# Displaying Drupal Teaser Nodes Horizontally

Tags: php, css, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming

I have created a custom theme and I am trying to display all the teaser nodes for the content in 3 rows. So I would have 3 rows and 4 teaser nodes in each row. I have created a node--teaser.tpl.php file and linked that to my template.php file. I am able to style each teaser node and it works fine but I am having trouble trying to make it so 4 nodes are on one row. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you try to do that via CSS.

for example:

```
.teaser
{
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
}
```

Hope this helps... Muhammad.